# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier Where to use

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, uistoryboard

I am using storyboards and I need to use this method to sync a view controller in the storyboard with a viewcontroller. I dont know where to add this method though. and how would i use it if its self. For instance

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

 MenuScreenViewController *controller = (MenuScreenViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                                                   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];
```

Is an example I got. However I don't want to create an instance of the menuscreenviewcontroller i want itsself and then be able to customise its properties. I am also not sure where I should put this code. Is it in loadview or viewwillload?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use that in viewDidLoad of your storyboard's initial view controller's to load some other view controllers also present in the storyboard file. As far as I know it is THE instance from storyboard (provided that you correctly identify it with the identifier within the attribute inspector). But unless there is reason to do so you would normally use Segue and inside

`(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

you would get your next view controller via

```
[segue destinationViewController];
```